# Is this T-SQL stored procedure written correctly?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, race-condition

I am new to SQL Server and T-SQL, but I do have some experience building applications in MS Access.

This stored procedure runs fine when I execute it from the application, however when I am debugging it in SSMS, I get an error

> Unable to Step. Invalid Operation.

but it will allow me to step through. Based on my research, it seems like I am creating a race condition but I have not been able to correctly fix the issue. I would also appreciate any advice to optimize this or fix any issues that are apparent.

**What the code does:**

This code is to enter a new customer into the database. The first select statement looks for an existing ID. If the ID is null, it will add a new customer. If the ID is not null, it will not add the customer. The same goes for the second `IF` statement to check if `@pName2` and `@pName3` are null before inserting these values.

Here is my code:

```
    @pUID nvarchar(16) = null, 
    @pName1 nvarchar(50) = null,
    @pName2 nvarchar(50) = null,
    @pName3 nvarchar(50) = null,
    @pAddress1 nvarchar(30) = null,
    @pAddress2 nvarchar(30) = null,
    @pAddress3 nvarchar(30) = null,
    @pZipCode nvarchar(30) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ID INT
    SELECT @ID = ID FROM tblCustomer WHERE strUID = @pUID

    IF @ID IS NULL
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @Customer_ID INT

        INSERT INTO tblCustomer(strUID, strName)
        VALUES(@pUID, @pName1)

        SET @Customer_ID = @@IDENTITY

        IF (@pName2 <> '') OR (@pName3 <> '')
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tblSecondaryCustomer(CustomerID, strName2, strName3)
            VALUES(@Customer_ID, @pName2, @pName3)
        END

        INSERT INTO tblAddress(CustomerID, strAddress1, strAddress2, strAddress3, strZipCode)
        VALUES(@Customer_ID, @pAddress1, @pAddress2, @pAddress3, @pZipCode)
    END
END
```

Comment: Where do you get the error? There are possible race conditions here; you may want to wrap this in a transaction and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`. But it's not apparent what your specific problem is because there isn't enough information provided. Note also that `IF (@pName2 <> '') OR (@pName3 <> '')` evaluates to false if both parameters are null, unless you've changed the default server settings.

Comment: Also keep in mind that since you added "= NULL" to each parameter you have made them optional. In effect you could call your procedure with no parameters and end up with rows containing nothing but NULL, unless you have constraints on your columns to prevent NULL.

Comment: @marc_s

I get the error at this line `SELECT @ID = ID FROM tblCustomer WHERE strUID = @pUID`. The error seems to only occur when the ID does not exist (when adding a new customer).

I am working my way up to wrapping this in a transaction and using `SCOPE_IDENTITY().`

As far as the second IF Statement, I would only like to insert these values if there is `pName2` is not null, or `pName3` is not null. If there is a value in `pName3` and not in `pName2`, I would like to insert the values and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your IF statement with the following:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM tblCustomer WHERE strUID = @pUID)
```

It doesn't seem your using @ID other than a check for existence...and you can use the `ISNULL` function to make sure you cover `NULL` cases...

```
IF (ISNULL(@pName2,'') <> '') OR (ISNULL(@pName3,'') <> '')
```

HTH

Dave